# Is there a way to search a string for a specific number or letter in C/C++

Tags: c++

I need to write a function that searches through a string and checks to see what data type is being used. For example, I need to figure out if the string contains a float, a char, or multiple ints. Then my function needs to pass that data to an overloaded function which will do something else with it.

Basically I'm looking for what function I should be using to search through the string and an example of how to use it would be nice.

Comment: Won't any string contain a character, even if it represents something else, because strings are just a series of characters?

Comment: First, you need to define a grammar, ie what types of inputs are accepted and how they should be formatted, and then you need to build a parser to parse said grammar.  There are lots of techniques for that last step depending on how complex your grammar is.

Comment: Perhaps you can 
a. Split the string by whatever delimiter you want (space?) and then 
b. Check each element separately?
You can easily find how to do a. and b. online.

Comment: Brayden Chapple,  "1.23 x 12 34", "1e5 + -12 +0", "0x1p2 \t 0x12 0123", each  contain all 3:  "float, a char, or multiple ints.".  As I see it, your parsing may match more than 1.  Note that many strings (e.g. "123") look like a `float` and an `int` as both will convert with `strtod()` and `strtol()`.

Answer (score 0):

To answer a question in the title:

Yes, there IS a way to search a string.

To look for any single character (for example, decimal point), use [find](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find).

To look for any one of the list of characters (for example, digits) use [find_first_of](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find_first_of).

Answer (score 0):

And to answer the question body, if you wish to know what "type" of thing a string contains you have two options:

- try to convert it to that type (using istringstream and operator >>)
- use a regular expression (or other pattern matching algorithm)

As already noted to you, this takes the effort on your part to clearly specify what uniquely constitutes each "type" of thing you wish to identify.

For example. In C++, `1` is an int, `1.0` is a double, etc.

Comment: you have a problem, you decide to fix it with regex. You now have two problems :-)

Comment: Lol, true. Dunno if I should suggest any other DFA parser or not...

Answer (score 0):

you could do a rough check, find_first_not_of("01234567890.") to see if it looks like a number or not. Then do lexical_cast (or stringstream <<) and see if it succeeds. If not then assume string.

Probably should do 0123456789 (not .) to see if its an integer, then if the first_not_of is "." do a lexicalcast as float else treat it as character string

probably sniff at first char to see if '-'

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want a parser that infers the type of the expression. This can be accomplished by trying different conversions and see if they succeed. Whenever they fail, jump to the next conversion. So a `1` would be a `std::uint8_t`, but a `-1` would be a `std::int8_t`, a `1.0` would be a `float` while a `1e+40` would be a `double` and so forth.

Fortunately C++17 added a function that does close to what you want: [`std::from_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/from_chars).

```
#include <charconv>
#include <string>
#include <variant>
#include <optional>
#include <cstdint>

namespace {
  using Value = std::variant<
    long double, double, float,
    std::uint64_t, std::int64_t,
    std::uint32_t, std::int32_t,
    std::uint16_t, std::int16_t,
    std::uint8_t, std::int8_t,
    std::string // last resort if nothing works
  >;  

  template <typename T>
  std::optional<T> parse_as(char const* const begin, char const* const end) {
    if (begin == end) return std::nullopt;
    T value{};
    auto const [ptr, ec] = std::from_chars(begin,end,value);
    if (ec == std::errc::result_out_of_range || ec == std::errc::invalid_argument || ptr != end) {
      return std::nullopt;
    }
    return value;
  }

  Value parse(std::string const& str) {
    auto const b = str.data();
    auto const e = str.data() + str.size();
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::uint8_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::int8_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::uint16_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::int16_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::uint32_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::int32_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::uint64_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<std::int64_t>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<float>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<double>(b,e)) return *r; 
    if (auto const r = parse_as<long double>(b,e)) return *r;
    return str;
  }
}
```

Here is a small test that shows how this works:

```
#include <iostream>

// helper type
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };

void show(std::string const& str) {
  std::visit(overloaded {
    [](std::uint8_t const arg) {
        std::cout << int{arg} << "\tsize: " << sizeof(arg) << "\n";
    },
    [](std::int8_t const arg) {
        std::cout << int{arg} << "\tsize: " << sizeof(arg) << "\n";
    },
    [](auto const arg) {
        std::cout << arg << "\tsize: " << sizeof(arg) << "\n";
    }
    }, parse(str));
}

int main() {
  show("hello");
  show("64");
  show("7000");
  show("-7000");
  show("-127");
  show("1.0");
  show("1e+40");
  show("1e+400");
}
```

This will correctly print:

```
hello   size: 32
64      size: 1
7000    size: 2
-7000   size: 2
-127    size: 1
1       size: 4
1e+40   size: 8
1e+400  size: 16
```

Here is a [live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/f9zo8vcj1).